# Match against "foo.bar" (with a full-stop/period)

Tags: mysql, match-against

I can search for rows with both `foo` and `bar` in the `col1`/`col2` using match against:

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM some_table
WHERE MATCH (col1,col2)
      AGAINST ('+foo +bar' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

But suppose I want to search for the exact phrase **"foo.bar"** *(with a full-stop in the middle)*. On [the docs page for Boolean Full-Text Searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-boolean.html), it doesn't mention full-stop being an operator, so I thought I could use:

```
AGAINST ('+foo.bar' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

However, this returns the same results as:

```
AGAINST ('+foo.couldBeAnything' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
AGAINST ('+foo' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
AGAINST ('+foo.*' IN BOOLEAN MODE); #Note you would expect this to look for instances of foo. followed by something, rather than just the same as foo
```

.

Why isn't this working as I expect? and how can I match against for `foo.bar`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a fulltext table readily available to test this out, but I believe this should work:

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM some_table
WHERE MATCH (col1,col2)
    AGAINST ('+\"foo.bar\"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Comment: @hayden I'm a bit rusty in my `MATCH AGAINST` knowledge, but I think what is happening is that it will only care about "words", so in your examples above `+foo.bar` will search for `foo` as required and `bar` as optional, same in `+foo.couldBeAnything`, it will split your input into separate words, each one needs their own operator. `\"foo.bar\"` only sort of works in that it requires both `foo` and `bar` to exist, and in that order, but the period is still ignored. If you want to search for other things than words, you may need to look outside `MATCH AGAINST`, like regexp or go outside MySQL.

Comment: If it's optional it seems a superflous operation, but it could be! With quotes it doesn't *quite* search for the precise substring nor the words in order in a field (but perhaps it is in order over multiple columns?). This is surprising.

I am thinking that I will have more control with regex, so may end up doing that.

Comment: @hayden the period isn't an operator, it's considered equivalent to a space, much like other stuff like commas, exclamation point and such. So it treats `foo` and `bar` as two separate words. I think that is the root of your issues. The idea of `FULLTEXT` is to search for words really.

Comment: I hadn't realised that! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To make this work, you need to suround your literal by a double quote: **"bar.foo"**, 
because the point is *probably equivalent* to **or** operator.

Comment: it's not an *or* operator, as `+foo.couldBeAnything` works the same as `+foo`.

Comment: Hello there, i think there is a confusion here, as it is described in the documentation, the or operator include both the case, when the string exist, or not, in other words: +foo.anyThing = +foo and +foo+anyThing = +foo (the first includes the last). best regards