# Full-stop/period operator in match against

Tags: mysql, match-against

I can search for all rows with `foo` in the `col1`/`col2` using match against:

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM some_table
WHERE MATCH (col1,col2)
      AGAINST ('foo' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

But suppose I want to search for all rows with **foo.** *(i.e. foo with a full-stop as the next character)*. On [the docs page for Boolean Full-Text Searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-boolean.html), **it doesn't mention full-stop being an operator**, so I thought I could use either of these:

```
AGAINST ('foo.' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
AGAINST ('"foo."' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
AGAINST ('"foo\."' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

However, this returns the same results as:

```
AGAINST ('foo.couldBeAnything' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
AGAINST ('foo' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
AGAINST ('foo*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

.

What is the `.` operator in this context? and how can I match-against `foo.`?

*Note: I first asked this [question about match-against `foo.bar`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12076780/match-against-foo-bar-with-a-full-stop-period) which led me to ask this follow up.*

Comment: can you try with `AGAINST ('foo\.couldBeAnything' IN BOOLEAN MODE);`

Comment: @jcho360 `foo\.couldBeAnything` does the same as `foo.couldBeAnything`.

Comment: Shot in the dark. What would `foo\\.couldBeAnything` do ?

Comment: Looks to me like the answer for this question will also be the same for this question as it was for the other question. Have you tried double quotes?

Comment: @NateC-K yes, see above for what I have tried, each seem to be the same as searching only for foo.

Comment: @Touki This does the same as searching for foo.

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full-stop, or indeed any punctuation, is **treated like a space** in a FULL-TEXT SEARCH, unfortunately this means there is no way to search for punctuation. The reasoning behind this is that text search is for finding "words" (which don't include punctuation).

To do such a search against punctuation, you could match against regular expressions, e.g. by using [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).