# Mysql Match... Against with special characters

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to filter and find the exact match for usernames that could have special characters.

I tried this with no luck:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE match(username) against('"J.N.J.T"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND username = 'J.N.J.T'
```

Sources:

https://getridbug.com/mysql/mysql-match-against-for-exact-phrase-working-partially/

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html

I also tried this but it didn't work:

```
... AGAINST ('+\"J.N.J.T\"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ...
```

Source:
[Match against "foo.bar" (with a full-stop/period)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12076780/match-against-foo-bar-with-a-full-stop-period)

Any ideas ?

PD: username have a full text index.

Comment: Did you read the comments to that answer? The `.` is treated like any other whitespace. Full-text indexes don't include punctuation, there's probably no way to do what you want.

Comment: Why do you need `MATCH` if you're also doing an exact match with `=`?

Comment: @Barmar The idea is to find the username quickly, as far as I know using match/against will drastically improve the query, but it will gave me more that one result depending on the characters in the username, for example "matt_fields10" and "@matt_fields100". By adding "AND username =" will return the exact username after reducing the options to only "matt_fields10" and "@matt_fields100". Doing it that way is quicker than a regular where clause "AND username =", the problem is not every special character will be found by match/against.

Comment: Since this worked: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33036298/mysql-fulltext-search-not-working-with-special-characters` I thought that what I need was possible.

Comment: Full-text indexes don't index 1-character words, so it won't find the initials between `.`

Comment: I think you misunderstood that answer. If you read the comments, you'll see that they said that the `.` are treated like any other word separator, it's not actually matching them.